# wso2 emm agent android ssl

Tags: android, wso2

After of my attempt to configure ssl for android emm agent I see:

> login failed. server unavailable, please contact administrator.

[I used this for configuration](http://www.wenda.io/questions/2602824/wso2-android-agent-certificates.html)

[Here is logcat](https://url.odesk.com/_01PX-Esb0ZWf2JGoFCbVIpLqXXHVvD3W0c)

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It works, but with important remark: it should be done BEFORE first run of server, or you need to paste default databases in WSO_HOME/repository/database

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate a bks file and include it in the Android agent in order to work. Please refer to this documentation for more info

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Android+Configurations

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
But as i said it works :-)
Here is command (for linux) for generation of bks for emm agent:

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:PATH_TO_bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar

keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -keystore emm_truststore.bks -storetype bks -storepass wso2carbon -file ca_cert.pem -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath ./

And if you ran server before, you need to remove all PATH_TO_WSO_EMM/repository/database and put there default databases from archive which you downloaded.
You need to do it because it add keystore info in database and will throw exception with message something like "Password is wrong or keystore is tampered".
If it someone need it i can show all commands cert and keystore generation here.
Just let me know